# filtering in dplyr between two columns where one is a list or vector

Tags: r, dplyr, strsplit

trying to filter this df down by comparing these two columns where `prod` exists in the `lob` column:

**reproducible code:**

```
df <- data.frame(prod = c("CES", "Access", "Access", "CES"), lob = c("Access;Entertainment", "CES", "Access", "Access;Entertainment;CES"))

    prod                      lob
1    CES     Access;Entertainment
2 Access                      CES
3 Access                   Access
4    CES Access;Entertainment;CES
```

**Expected Result:**

```
    prod                      lob
1 Access                   Access
2    CES Access;Entertainment;CES
```

I've tried splitting the lob column into a vector, or a list containing elements, and then used `dplyr filter` with `grepl(prod, lob)`, or `prod %in% lob`, but neither seem to work

```
df %>%
filter(prod %in% lob)

df %>%
mutate(lob = strsplit(lob, ";")) %>%
filter(prod %in% lob)

df %>%
mutate(lob = strsplit(lob, ";")) %>%
filter(grepl(prod), lob)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would probably be easiest just to add a `rowwise()` in there

```
df %>%
  mutate(lob = strsplit(lob, ";")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(prod %in% lob) %>% 
  as.data.frame() # rowwise makes it a tibble, this changes it back if needed
```

If you don't really want to do the `mutate()`, you can do

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(prod %in% strsplit(lob, ";")[[1]])
```

Comment: "Modern" variant with purrr and magrittr: `df %>% mutate(lob = strsplit(lob, ";")) %>% filter(map2_lgl(prod, lob, is_in))`

Answer (score 1):

With `stringr::str_detect`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(as.character(lob), as.character(prod)))
```

Comment: This requires that a regex is a substitute for exact matching after splitting, eg `str_detect("apples and oranges; bananas", "apples")` should be false, but maybe the OP knows such cases aren't relevant.